# $f-g$ finite $a.e.$ implies $f$ finite a.e.?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(A,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and let $f,g$ be extended real measurable functions on $A$. Now suppose $f-g$ and $g$ are finite a.e.  Is $f$ also finite a.e?

**My attempt**

If $f-g$ is finite a.e., then $w\in\{\mid f-g\mid=\infty\}\rightarrow \mid f(w)-g(w)\mid\leq \mid f(w)\mid+\mid g(w)\mid=\infty$.
But there is the case when $\mid g(w)\mid=\infty$, letting $\mid f(w)\mid$ free to take any nonnegative number. So I can't conclude that $w\in\{\mid f\mid=\infty\}$, and that $0\leq\mu(\mid f-g\mid=\infty )\leq\mu(\mid f\mid=\infty).$

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Yes. This is true. Use the triangle inequality as follows $$|f|=|f-g+g|\le |f-g|+|g|$$

and the fact that for two zero sets $D_1$ and $D_2$, $D_1\cup D_2$ is also a zero set.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f= (f-g) + g$, $f$ is infinite if at least one of $f-g$ and $g$ is, i.e. $$\mu\{w : f(w) \in \{\pm \infty\}\} \leq \mu\{w : (f-g)(w) \in \{\pm \infty\} \}  + \mu\{w : g(w) \in \{\pm \infty\} \}$$ $$= 0+0 = 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is equal to $(f-g)+g$. In particular, it is the sum of two functions, each of which is finite a.e. Therefore, $f$ is also finite a.e.